# Syntax for variables in html directory path

Tags: html, variables, path, directory

I have a page with loads of repetitive directory paths for images, and all of those images need to replace with new files (that are the same file name, but in a different directory) when duplicating the page. Rather than updating the folder name in each directory I'd like to replace it with a variable and just change that variable once when duplicating pages.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations (like below) but I can't find anything that works, and google efforts were unsuccessful.

```
var Shirtloc='Shirts/FolderNameThatWouldBeUpdated/'

<img src="'Shirtloc'+title.gif" width="952" height="119">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is not a programming language but a markup language and as such does not provide variables or any other programming tools. This is where serverside scripting comes in, with PHP, ASP.NET and JSP as the most common examples.

Technically, you could do it with Javascript as well but you should not attempt to do that, as it comes with a myriad of problems and possible future issues that you really would not want to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the information! How would I go about accomplishing this with php?

Comment: The right way would be using [templating](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/17/getting-started-with-php-templating/) but if this is all dynamic content you need or want, stuff like [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/) would also be doable.

If these two links don't help you there are various tutorial pages for PHP and pretty much any that deals with printing variables will give you all you need to do something as elementary as this.

Comment: I don't need to make a template, I already have the page made, and it doesn't have any other dynamic content. Just basic images that need their directories updated easily. How can I use a php variable as a directory path? What would the syntax be like?

Comment: Somewhere at the top of your HTML: `<?php $shirtloc = "Shirts/FolderNameThatWouldBeUpdated/"; ?>` and in the spot where you need it: `<img src="<?php echo $shirtloc; ?>title.gif" width="952" height="119">` Having said that: templates are really a lot more versatile and if you're anywhere near the start of your project, you really want to set this up well. There are more problems just like this one that you'll run into without proper templating.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed!! And the website is pretty far in development, and in my scenario templating isn't really necessary.