# Set path based on specific directory in HTML?

Tags: html, path

Let's say I am in

`main/component1/index.html`

and I want my html button to link me to `main/component2/`.

But the same `index.html` file is also used for the directory

`main/component3/dir1/index.html`

and I still want to link it to `main/component2/`.

*Specifications:*

- I specifically know my main.
- The root will be variable, I want to be able to package `main/`, then unpackage in another directory with working links.
- If there is no HTML solution to this, then I'll try to write a solution in JS; I just wanted to know if it was possible in pure HTML.

##### How would I go about doing this? Thank you!

Comment: "Folder" is a Windows concept. On the web, and Unix where it originated from, these are "directories". Folders are not the same thing.

Comment: My mistake, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question - no, you can't make it with HTML only, because HTML is not programing language, but markup language.

You can make relative and absoulte paths but not "variabled" paths.

Read more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18321468/2719670

Comment: Ok, thanks, that link was helpful! I ended up writing a JS func that worked well. I'll probably close this thread soon as I don't think its helpful to others if the solution is in another language.